# How to access element that is in the Main() method from an indexer that is in another class?

Tags: c#, .net, class, indexer

Suppose we have the code below. I want to access the element that is highlighted by a comment in the Main() method in the class that has an indexer.
The indexer also has a comment in the "set" section of the indexer code describing where the element is to be accessed. If I am missing something, any **advice** would be much *appreciated*.

**Main():**

```
arrayaccess aa = new arrayaccess();
string a = "karl";
if (a is string)
Console.WriteLine(aa[a]);
else
{
    double d = Convert.ToDouble(a);
    d = Math.Floor(d);
    Console.WriteLine(aa[Convert.ToByte(d)]);
}
//set code
aa[3] = "karl";//the name (string) karl is to be accessed in the indexer of "ArrayClass" class.
```

```
class arrayaccess
    {

        private string[] names = new string[] { "carl", "karl", "doe", "john" };
        public string this[object index]
        {
            get
            {
                if (index is string)
                {
                    if (names.Contains(index))
                        return "found";
                    else return "not found";
                }
                else
                {

                    if (Convert.ToByte(index) >= names.Length)
                        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Index should be less than or equal to 3");
                    return names[Convert.ToByte(index)];

                }

            }
            set
            {
                //it's easy to do with the get accessor
                if (names.Contains(/*value here*/))//want to access here
                    throw new ArgumentException("Sorry, duplicate" +
                        "values not allowed");
                else names[Convert.ToByte(index)] = value;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting an error? Is something not working?

Comment: If the problem has to do with accessing the incoming value in the `set` accessor, is there some reason why you couldn't just say `if (names.Contains(value))`?

Comment: No error, I just want to check if the name ("karl") passed with aa[0]="karl" that will be utilized by the set{} of indexer is in the "names" array of the arrayaccess class.

Comment: Then what are you asking? What do you want feedback on?

Comment: If all you want is what to replace `/*value here*/` with ... then try `value.ToString()`.

Comment: BTW, since your backing store is an array, and arrays are fixed-length, you might want to put a check in your `set` method that `index` is not out of range.

Comment: Yes, I used your code line "if(names.Contains(value))" and it worked. I was missing the "value" keyword in Contains(). It wasn't working previously when I tried. Now that you refreshed my memory with the line of code. Now it works and generates the exception too. Thanks so much.

Comment: @jimnkey why `.ToString()` - it's already a string, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "value" keyword in your code:

```
if(names.Contains(value))
```